# Reading response body from ServerHttpResponse Spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am trying to read response body from `ServerHttpResponse` in a FilterFactory class that extents `AbstractGatewayFilterFactory`. The method executes, but I never see the log line printed. Is this the correct approach to read response ? If yes, what am I missing here ?

```
@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        ServerHttpRequest.Builder reqBuilder = exchange.getRequest().mutate();
        ServerHttpResponse originalResponse = exchange.getResponse();
        DataBufferFactory bufferFactory = originalResponse.bufferFactory();
        ServerHttpResponseDecorator decoratedResponse = new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(originalResponse) {
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                if (body instanceof Flux) {
                    Flux<? extends DataBuffer> fluxBody = (Flux<? extends DataBuffer>) body;
                    return super.writeWith(fluxBody.map(dataBuffer -> {
                        byte[] content = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                        dataBuffer.read(content);
                        log.info("Response : {}", new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                        return bufferFactory.wrap(content);
                    }));
                }
                return super.writeWith(body);
            }
        }; 
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate()
                .request(reqBuilder.build())
                .response(decoratedResponse)
                .build());
    };
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory`?